# The normalizer of SU(n) in U(m)?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, spin-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$Consider the [special unitary group $\SU(5)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) and the [unitary group $\U(16)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group).

Below I specify a *specfic* way to embed $\SU(5) \subset \U(16)$:

1. First we can embed the spin group $\Spin(10)\subset \U(16)$. Here we choose the $\mathbf{16}$-dimensional spinor representation of $\Spin(10)$ to be also the $\mathbf{16}$-dimensional fundamental representation of $\U(16)$. Thus, the data for the representation:
   $$\text{$\mathbf{16}$ in $\Spin(10)$ as $\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$}$$
   gives us an action of $\Spin(10)$ and $\U(16)$ on the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^{16}$.
2. Then, we can embed $\SU(5)$ into $\Spin(10)$. See [the discussion of this embedding
   of $\SU(n)$ into $\Spin(2n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318145/is-sun-subset-textspin2n). Here we choose the complex-conjugated fundamental representation $\overline{\mathbf 5}$, the anti-symmetric representation $\mathbf{10}$ and the 1-dimensional representation $\mathbf 1$ of $\SU(5)$:
   $$\text{$\overline{\mathbf 5} \oplus \mathbf{10} \oplus  \mathbf 1$ in $\SU(5)$ as $\mathbf{16}$ in $\Spin(10)$}.$$
   Again, the data for the representation gives us an action of $\SU(5)$ on $\mathbb{C}^{16}$, which further gives an embedding of $\SU(5)$ into $\U(16)$.

### Question

Then my question is about the *normalizer* of this $\SU(5)$ inside $\U(16)$, which certainly depends on the embedding that I provided above. So what is the [*normalizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of this $\SU(5)$ inside $\U(16)$? My suspicion is that it may be $\U(5)$, but it could also be larger than $\U(5)$ with more $\U(1)$ factors if I was mistaken ….

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$It's $\U(5) \times \U(1) \times \U(1)$.

We have a natural map from the normalizer of $G$ to the outer automorphism group of $G$. The outer automorphism group of $G$ is $\mathbb Z/2$, generated by the inverse transpose / complex conjugation.

This map is trivial, because if it were nontrivial, an element mapping to $1 \in \mathbb Z/2$ would give an isomorphism between this representation and the complex conjugate  $\mathbf 5 \oplus \overline{\mathbf {10}} \oplus \mathbf 1$, which does not exist as these are not isomorphic.

Let us check that the kernel of this natural map, for any $G \subseteq H$, is $G C_{H}(G)$, where $C_H(G)$ is the centralizer of $G$ in $H$.  To do this, note that every element $h$ of the kernel acts by conjugation on $G$ as an inner automorphism. By the definition of inner automorphism, there exists $g \in G$ such that the action of $h$ by conjugation on $G$ equals the action of $g$ by conjugation on $G$. It follows that $g^{-1} h$ acts trivially by conjugation on $G$. By definition, this means $g^{-1} h$ lies in the centralizer of $G$. So $g = g \cdot (g^{-1}h) \in G C_H(G)$. Conversely, every element of $G C_H(G)$ normalizes $G$ and acts by inner automorphisms on $G$, since $C_H(G)$ acts trivially and $G$ acts by inner automorphisms.

The centralizer is $\U(1) \times \U(1) \times \U(1)$ since there are three non-isomorphic irreducible representations of $G$, so the centralizer of $G$ consists of matrices acting by scalars on these three representations.

So the normalizer is the product, inside $\U(16)$, of this $\SU(5)$ and the $\U(1) \times \U(1) \times \U(1)$ scalars. We can check that this product is isomorphic to $\U(5) \times \U(1) \times \U(1)$ by letting $\U(5)$ act on $\overline{\mathbf 5}$ by the dual of the standard representation, $\mathbf{10}$ by the $\wedge^2$ of the standard representation, and $\mathbf 1$ trivially, and letting the two factors of $\U(1)$ act by multiplication on the last two representations.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer! +1. It is possible, are you sure that there are no shared finite normal subgroup between each of $U(5)$ and two $U(1)$?

Comment: @wonderich Yes, since every nontrivial element of $U(5)$ acts nontrivially on the five-dimensional representation, but every element of $U(1) \times U(1)$ acts trivially on that representation.

Comment: What is "this representation" in "an isomorphism betwee this representation and the complex conjugate"?

Comment: @LSpice I mean $\overline{\bf 5} \oplus {\bf 10} \oplus  {\bf 1}$.

Comment: @Will Sawin, I was wondering whether the (5) and two (1) share a common $\mathbb{Z}/2$, so we need to mod out $\mathbb{Z}/2$ twice...?

Comment: @wonderich Do you disbelieve the argument in my previous comment?

Comment: I think you are correct. Thanks -- and from your answer, it also means that there are no additional discrete sectors like $\mathbb{Z}/N$ outside the U(5)×U(1)×U(1)? Thank you so much! (I will accept the answer in 1 week if all minor issues are clear to me)

Comment: @wonderich Yes, because the centralizer consists of matrices that act as scalars on each irreducible representation (Schur's lemma), and thus is $U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1)$ (and because of the outer automorphism argument).

Comment: @Will Sawin, thanks so much. I have a naive question, suppose we take a special unitary subgroup of $SU(5)$ which contains both the $U(2)=U(1)\times SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $U(3)=U(1)\times SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}/3$ but mod out the shared $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3$ subgroups between two of $U(1)$. Define this special unitary group as $S(U(2)\times U(3))$ which is the subgroup of $SU(5)$. What would be the normalizer of this $S(U(2)\times U(3))$ within $U(16)$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I accepted your wonderful answer. I ask another one which is more subtle mathoverflow.net/questions/384694, maybe it is obvious to you.

Comment: Can I make sure the way you defined $GZ(G)$? The $Z(G)$ is usually the center but now the centralizer. And $GZ(G)$ is?

Comment: @wonderich Sorry, by $Z(G)$ I meant the centralizer, and by $G Z(G)$ the set of all products of an element of $G$ with an element of the centralizer of $G$.

Comment: Excuse me, could we break your whole-sentence paragraph into two sentences to make it clear about the logic? This is rather long to follow...  *"The kernel of this natural map, for any ⊆, is (), where () is the centralizer of  in , since every element of the kernel acts by conjugation as an inner automorphism, i.e. is an element of  times something that acts trivially by conjugation, i.e. is an element of  times something in its centralized. So the normalizer is ()."*

Comment: (I hope you can correct me on your logic --- I am sorry to possibly mix up your logic in that paragraph.)

Comment: @wonderich Maybe this helps?

Comment: @Will, thanks so much! the normalizer of this SU(5) inside U(16) is U(5) $\times$ U(1)$^2$. Suppose we ask differently: the normalizer of this SU(5) inside Spin(10) [instead of U(16)], do we get U(5)? or do we get extra how many U(1) factors still? (I just wanted to make sure I did not miss your logic.) What precisely it is?

Comment: @Will Sawin: the normalizer of this SU(5) inside U(16) is U(5) × U(1)$^2$. Suppose we ask differently: the normalizer of this SU(5) inside Spin(10) [instead of U(16)], do we get U(5)?

Comment: @wonderich Please do not ask me the same question twice. I am not sure what the answer is.

Comment: Sorry, now I think that the normalizer of this SU(5) inside Spin(10) at least contains a SU(5) $\times \mathbb{Z}/4$ where $\mathbb{Z}/4$ is a center of Spin(10).